# The route in Flask redirecting twice

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/customers_products/<name>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def customers_products(name):
    ##pass
        return redirect(url_for('customer_payment',name=name))
    return render_template('customers_products.html',name=name,products=products)

@app.route('/customer_payment/<name>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def customer_payment(name):
    order_numbers = [i for i in range(101,400)]
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT order_no FROM order_receipts'
    cursor.execute(query)
    numbers = cursor.fetchall()

    numbers_used = []
    for number in numbers:
        numbers_used.append(number[0])
        order_numbers.remove(number[0])

            
            
    order_num = random.randint(order_numbers[1],order_numbers[-1])
    print('Number 1:',order_num)
    print('Number 2:',order_num)

    ##pass
```

**Output**

```
Number 1: 168
Number 2: 168
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2021 23:14:39] "[37mGET /customer_payment/<name> HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
Number 1: 326
Number 2: 326
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2021 23:14:39] "[37mGET /customer_payment/<name> HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

I had a problem that although I only used redirect for one time then the route `customer_payment` redirected twice and I could not find out where is the problem that the result is not the same as I expected.

Comment: Your code does not appear to be correct. Should the render_template call be on the other view? Also, what client are you using to test this? A web browser? Which one?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Also, from one GET to the next your call to randint is going to produce a different result. Why would you expect it to produce the same result?

Comment: I mean if I specify the variable ```order_num```

Comment: Chrome can sometimes perform a prefetch on GET URLs depending on how the URL is used within the browser. This would appear as two GETs in a row.

Comment: how to make it into one instead of two?

Comment: You normally can’t. GETs are idempotent meaning they should not change server state when hit with the same parameters. I.e. don’t worry about the double-hit and either make your handler idempotent or use a different method like POST.